# Tags in oneboxed messages are broken

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

I oneboxed [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19272966#19272966) that contained tags. The result is [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20669839#20669839). But the tags in the onebox don't go to the tags on the site, they go to:

```
https://chat.stackexchange.com//codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory
```

Can tags in oneboxed messages please link to the actual tags?